# Can't center and space card deck for react js bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've been having a hard time trying to get some cards to fit my page. I'm basically trying to make 6 cards fit in to my page, 3 on the top and 3 on the bottom. I've been using card decks, but can't seem to get the CSS right.

[image]

I want them to cover most of the screen, but still have space in between themselves. Also, when I try to add CSS (width or padding), it to justs breaks everything, and for some reason I can't manually specify a width and height at the same time, width just overrides both.

```html
            <React.Fragment>
                <CardDeck
                    style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        padding: "10px",
                        width: "80rem",

                    }}
                    class="mx-auto"
                    className="text-center"
                >
                    <Card style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                        <Card.Img
                            variant="top"
                            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg"
                        />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>
                                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                the bulk of the card's content.
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <Card style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                        <Card.Img
                            variant="top"
                            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg"
                        />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>
                                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                the bulk of the card's content.
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <Card style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                        <Card.Img
                            variant="top"
                            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg"
                        />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>
                                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                the bulk of the card's content.
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </CardDeck>
            </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up the card columns component from react boostrap. I think it works pretty well; still I don't know what the heck it's doing half the time.

```html
<CardColumns
                    style={{
                        padding: "25px",
                    }}
                >
                    {" "}
                    <a
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.props.history.push("/register");
                        }}
                    >
                        <OverlayTrigger
                            placement="right"
                            delay={{ show: 150, hide: 100 }}
                            overlay={this.renderTooltip(this.props, "registrar")}
                        >
                            <Card>
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <Card.Img
                                        variant="top"
                                        src="https://espacio.fundaciontelefonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/block_chain_1100x525-1-1100x550.jpg"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>Registrar Datos</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                        Registra de forma confiable los datos de personas que han
                                        sido infectadas por COVID-19.
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                    </a>
                    <a
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.props.history.push("/predict");
                        }}
                    >
                        <OverlayTrigger
                            placement="right"
                            delay={{ show: 150, hide: 100 }}
                            overlay={this.renderTooltip(this.props, "examen")}
                        >
                            <Card>
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <Card.Img
                                        variant="top"
                                        src="https://www.paho.org/sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_full/public/hero/2020-03/covid-19-1190x574-2-full.jpg?h=fdc0eb87&itok=CerQCpzv"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>Examen Virtual de Covid-19</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                        De un examen virtual de Covid-19 para ver si hay una
                                        probabilidad de que estés infectado.
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                    </a>
                    <a
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.props.history.push("/faq");
                        }}
                    >
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>Preguntas Frecuentes</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Averigua la información relevante sobre la prevención y
                                    tratamiento del nuevo corona virus, dicho por la Organización
                                    Mundial de la Salud.
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                            <Card.Footer>
                                <small className="text-muted">
                                    Actualizado hace 30 minutos
                                </small>
                            </Card.Footer>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                    <a
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.props.history.push("/groups");
                        }}
                    >
                        <Card>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <Card.Img
                                    variant="top"
                                    src="https://elmontonero.pe/upload/uploads_images/columna_alan_6.jpg"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>Grupos de riesgo</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Averigua cuales son los grupos de riesgo ante el Covid-19.
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </CardColumns>
```